# Tokenize a delimited string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, split, tokenize

I wrote a function in MySQL to split a delimited string into tokens, but right now, it only returns the first token it encounters after the start position (pos).  **Is there a way to get it to return tokens as a result set with one column containing all of the parsed tokens?**

Here is my current function code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `split_string_multi_byte`(
  source_string VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_string, delim, pos),
       CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_string, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, "");
END
```

Here are some parameters that I entered in my Navicat database development and admin client:

[image: Input parameters]

That returns the following results:

[image: Results in Navicat]

See how only "1" is returned.  I would like to see all of the tokens if possible.  However, I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: So what is the result that you would like to get? Please show it, as tabular text.

Comment: You cannot return a result set from a function, only a scalar value. You could write to a temporary or permanent table. You should explain what you are trying to achieve rather than the solution you have lighted upon.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `SPLIT`(s varchar(200), c char, i integer) RETURNS varchar(200) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE retval varchar(200);
  WITH RECURSIVE split as (
    select 1 as x,substring_index(substring_index(s,c,1),c,-1) as y, s 
    union all 
    select x+1,substring_index(substring_index(s,c,x+1),c,-1),s from split where x<= (LENGTH(s) - LENGTH(REPLACE(s,c,''))) 
  )
  SELECT y INTO retval FROM split WHERE x=i ;
  return retval;
END
```

`SELECT SPLIT('a,b,c,d,e,f',',',3);` results in 'c'

Because you cannot return a table from a function (in MySQL), you could do something like this if you want results in a table:

```
SET @tekst = 'aap,noot,mies,wim,zus,jet';
WITH RECURSIVE abc as (
   SELECT 1 as c 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT c+1 
   FROM abc WHERE c<=15) 
select c,split(@tekst,',',c) as t
from abc 
where not split(@tekst,',',c) is null;
```

output:

```
+------+------+
| c    | t    |
+------+------+
|    1 | aap  |
|    2 | noot |
|    3 | mies |
|    4 | wim  |
|    5 | zus  |
|    6 | jet  |
+------+------+
```